# Xcode provisioning profile errors

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, provisioning, signing

I'm trying to set up Xcode to test a game I have developed with Unity. I'm getting these strange errors about provisioning profiles and signing. When I search for any solutions to this they all say "Xcode will automatically generate these for you" but it doesn't. It just errors. Other places say "Click the fix issue button" but there is no fix issue button. Here are some screenshots of the errors:

[image]

I have entered my Identity and signing details and team:

[image]

And for some reason there are no provisioning profiles at all, and "Download All" doesn't actually download anything:

[image]

I also found another comment from apple that told me to download the profiles manually from the apple website, but the page he mentioned wasn't even there.

Been going around in circles for hours, I would really appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: you can try to go to click on the main project root in the left side panel which should reveal the project properties. Scroll to the bottom and there is a Linked Frameworks and Libraries. Remove the StoreKit.framework, go to Signing, disable the 'Automatically manage signing' option and enable it again. If needed, set your Team to 'None' and set it back to your Personal Development Team, which should trigger the automatic provisioning mechanism. Moreover, you can login to https://developer.apple.com/account/ and can get the provisioning profile.

Comment: This got me past the errors! Thank you so much this was driving me mad.